# Azure Function V1 Build issue

Tags: c#, azure

Two day ago i started to experience an issue during build of my Azure Function App V1. Build process halts on GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadata task, particularly on AWSSDK.Core.dll assembly.

[image]

I have successfully used Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.38 for several months. But something changed.

I can solve this by downgrading Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions to 1.0.37. In this case there is no such build step.

Do somebody know what could cause such an issue? Or any suggests to investigate it further?

Comment: By "halts", do you mean the build hangs and never completes?

Comment: Thats rigth, it hangs and never completes

Comment: possibly related: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/8401

Answer (score 1):

This looks similar to [GitHub issue#287](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-vs-build-sdk/issues/287).

Try adding below piece of code in your .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="HackMoveNativeDlls" BeforeTargets="_GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadataPostPublish">
  <Move SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin/Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin/temp"/>
  <Move SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin/temp"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="HackRestoreNativeDlls" AfterTargets="_GenerateFunctionsExtensionsMetadataPostPublish">
  <Move SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin/temp/Cosmos.CRTCompat.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin"/>
  <Move SourceFiles="$(PublishDir)bin/temp/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ServiceInterop.dll" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)bin"/>
</Target>
```

*This is a hack to resolve this problem. It happens to functions that use CosmosDB SDKs.*